# There is a high priority keys combination for the opening terminal in Linux if UI is hanging on?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, priority, hang

Several times I've run into with the problem of Ubuntu hanging when a memory leak happens in some application process (Chrome/Sublime/etc.). As a result, the keyboard and mouse stop reacting.

I even couldn't open the terminal to type `top` to find the guilty app and kill it.

Is there some highest priority key combination for opening a terminal in Linux?

Comment: Be patient. Probably your system is getting very slow because it is using swap. In this case it has to free some memory by writing it to the hard disk and read other data from the disk if you need to wake up a process or want to create new processes.

Answer (score 1):

If your XServer hangs, you may try using the Magic SysRq key combination to detach keyboard control from X.

<kbd>ALT + SysRq + R</kbd>

If not printed on your Keyboard: SysRq is on the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> button.

Then switch to a text terminal:

<kbd>CTRL + ALT + F1</kbd>

Log in there and kill what must die.

By default detaching the keyboard should be available, but some features are disabled for security reasons. Check the output of `cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` versus [this list](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html) and set the mask you like or allow all keys (`1`) like described [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-all-sysrq-functions-on-linux).

Comment: i'll try it, thank you!